# Two different result about DateTimeZone.forID

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have this part of code for getting un ID of DateTimeZone

```
String timeZoneId = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID();
DateTimeZone desTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID(timeZoneId);
```

When this part of code is executed in the war file, I got timeZoneId = "GMT+01:00"

But when I run this part of code in main method I got timeZoneId = "Europe/Paris"

The first one throws an exception in second line :
the datetime zone id 'GMT+01:00' is not recognised

I don't know why I've two different results !!!

How to get the same result in the war file and the main method (Europe/Paris)?

Thank's

Edit : add the full code of the method :

public static DateTime toLocalDateTime(String gmtDate) {

```
if (StringUtils.isBlank(gmtDate)) {
    return null;
}

DateTime gmt = new DateTime(gmtDate, DateTimeZone.UTC);

String timeZoneId =  Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID();
DateTimeZone desTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID(timeZoneId);
DateTimeZone.setDefault(desTimeZone);
LocalDateTime locDateTime = gmt.withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault()).toLocalDateTime();

return locDateTime.toDateTime();
```

}

Comment: I suppose you don't want just hardcode timezone id in your code? What you want then?

Comment: I want when i call DateTimeZone.forID(timeZoneId) i got "Europe/Paris" or others id depend of the city

Comment: So you want system default timezone?

Comment: i've add the full method to more clarity

Comment: And what is `gmtDate` exactly?

Comment: gmtDate = "2020-02-03T10:09:21.154Z"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use the modern *java.time* classes that replaced both frameworks you are mixing in your code.

```
java.time.Instant
.parse( "2020-02-03T10:09:21.154Z" ) 
.atZone(
    ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" )
)
```

## Details

You do not provide enough detail to make a definite diagnosis. You would need to describe exactly how you are running exactly what code.

And I’m not sure it is worth the effort to pursue this issue, for two reasons:

- You are using `Calendar` which is a terrible class, part of the original date-date time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.
- You are using `DateTimeZone` from *Joda-Time*, the predecessor to those *java.time* classes. This project is now in maintenance-mode.

## *java.time*

So instead use *java.time*.

Get the JVM’s current default time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
```

If you want to know the offset used currently in that zone, use [`ZoneRules`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html).

```
ZoneRules rules = z.getRules() ;
ZoneOffset offset = rules.getOffset( Instant.now() ) ;
```

Be clear about zone versus offset. An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the prime meridian. An offset looks like `+05:30`. A time zone is much more. A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. A time zone name is in the format of `Continent/Region`.

## ISO 8601 strings

If given text in standard ISO 8601 format such as `2020-02-03T10:09:21.154Z`, understand that this represents a moment as seen at UTC, that is, with an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. The `Z` on the end means UTC and is pronounced “Zulu”.

Parse such input as a `java.time.Instant`. This class presents a moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2020-02-03T10:09:21.154Z" ) ;
```

To see this moment through the wall-clock time of a time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

The `instant` and `zdt` objects both represent the same moment, the same point on the timeline.

## Moments

When tracking moments, specific points on the timeline, never use `LocalDateTime`. In both Joda-Time and java.time frameworks, that class represents a date with a time-of-day but lacks any concept of zone or offset. Lacking that context, that class cannot represent a moment.

Comment: I've add more detail in the post with full code of the method

Comment: Thank's Basil, I resolve it by replacing Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID() by the ZoneId